# Check whether a closed point of a Noetherian affine scheme is a local complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, complete-intersection, noetherian

Suppose that $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $A$ is the ring $k[a,b,c,d]/(ac-b^2,bd-c^2,ad-bc)$. Let $X$ be Spec$A$, and $m$ be the maximal ideal of $A$ generated by the quotient images of $a,b,c,d$ in $A$.Let $x_0$ be the closed point of $X$ corresponding to the maximal ideal $m$ of $A$.Then is $x_0$ a local complete intersection closed subscheme of $X$?How do I justify whether it is or not?
Thank you very much in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?  Certainly every Zariski open neighborhood of that point in $X$ is not a local complete intersection scheme.  However, the point you mention is set-theoretically "cut out" by the two equations $a=0$ and $d=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind guidance. I was asking whether $x_0$ is a local complete intersection closed subscheme of $X$. Could you explain why every Zariski open neighborhood of the point $x_0$ in $X$ is not a local complete intersection scheme?I have trouble justifying this. And could you explain why the point $x_0$ is set-theoretically cut out by the two equations $a=0$ and $d=0$?Thank you very much.

Comment: For your comment that the point $x_0$ of $X$ is set-theoretically "cut out" by the 2 equations $a=0$ and $d=0$, could I justify this by saying that in the ring $A$, if the quotient images of $a,d$ in $A$ are both set to be zero, then the three relations defining $A$ imply that the quotient images of $b,c$ in $A$ also vanish?Thanks.

Comment: Yes, for the second claim, I am just saying that the unique prime component of the ideal $\langle ac-b^2, bd-c^2, ad-bc, a,d \rangle$ is the maximal ideal $\langle a,b,c,d\rangle$.  For the first claim, if you adjoin the elements $a$ and $d$ to the ideal, the quotient ring is zero-dimensional and Cohen-Macaulay.  From this it follows that the original ring is Cohen-Macaulay and that pair of elements is a regular sequence.  Since it is a regular sequence, the original ideal has LCI quotient if and only if the zero-dimensional, Cohen-Macaulay quotient is LCI.  It is not even Gorenstein.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind guidance and help. I will try my best to digest your comments.